Copy animation channels from one animation to another?
I have two animations: One where the person stands idle and another where they are nodding their head but with body movements that don't look right.
I'd like to copy the head and neck animations from the nodding animation and replace the head action in the idle animation.
Is this possible? If so, then how?

You can copy paste the keyframes of a bone only

Thanks. I didn't realise that by selecting the bone in pose mode I could show just that bone's animations. That solves it. Thanks
